# I saw a scene in Sons of Anarchy yesterday, where Jax wears sunglasses vs where Jax was wearing sunglasses

Tags: grammar, past-tense, continuous

Is it correct to say: ''I saw a scene yesterday where Jax wears sunglasses''

or is the only correct form: ''Where Jax was wearing sunglasses''

I was in doubt whether the first one is okay to use.

Comment: By the way, that is an interesting structure, my knowledge of English, as limited as it is, makes me consider the first version wrong because of inconsistent tenses: `I saw a scene where Jax wears` the correct version would be `I saw a scene where Jax wore`. But some gut feeling agrees with the first version also being correct, not sure why, so is it really correct and why?

Comment: There is a convention that you can refer to events in movies, books, songs, and so in in the present tense. You couldn't say "In the Civil War, the Confederate army wears gray uniforms." But you can say "In *300*, the Spartan soldiers wear very little armor."

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically correct, but the first avoids superfluous wording.